# Why does my three.js transparent texture break unless part of it is out of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to texture a plane, with a PNG that has transparency.

When I view the shape, the transparent sections in the PNG go black.

[image]

However, oddly, when any part of the image clips out of the viewport, the transparency starts to work again (which is obviously the effect I'm requiring):

[image]

I created an isolated example, the plane is created in the regular way:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  loader.load('img/message2.png', function(tex) {
      var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map : tex, transparent: true });
      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 14, 10 );
      var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mat );
      plane.position.set(0,0,-10);
      scene.add( plane );
  });
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your material add `alphaTest: 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

Try set for material:

```
depthWrite: false
```

Or

```
alphaTest: 0.5
```